# How do I deploy Vuejs App backed by Laravel, In similar fashion we usually deploy laravel app or I need seperate frontend and backend instances?

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2, single-page-application

Hello guys I have been deploying Laravel applications on the server for a while, I have just created a SPA(Single Page App) Laravel + Vuejs how do I deploy it ? Just like normal laravel app or I need separate Frontend(Vuejs) and Backend (Laravel) instances ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is same as regular laravel app deployment.
run `npm run production` and after that make whole project as zip and put it on serve and just follow the steps as regular laravel project.

Comment: Thanks for replying, when I run "npm run deploy" is says ""missing script: deploy"

Comment: sorry It will be `npm run production`

Comment: @ZubaerHaque I am facing a problem during deployment laravel+vue. Would you please help me. I am deploying after `npm run production` and then as regular steps. But, I am facing some problem. Would you please visit the link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57991720/deploy-laravelvuejs-application

Comment: link says page not found